# REST API - where to pass ID parameter? in URL or in header

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I wrote a small web service with REST API and after reading a few tutorials I cannot come to a conclusive answer.

If I wish to pass a user id to the REST API, should I pass it in the URL like so:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/users?userid=716360178
```

Or like so:

```
127.0.0.1:8080/users/716360178
```

If I were to use the second one, how will I be able to retrieve the user ID from the URL? I'm using nodejs + express.

Please advise.

Comment: the second one is more "restful", but both are fine

Comment: @ZdravkoDanev, If I were to use the second one, how would I get to the user id? I'm using nodejs with Express.

Comment: @DavidFaiz: You may look at my simple REST API example in nodejs [here](https://github.com/mevdschee/js-crud-api/blob/master/app.js). I hope it helps you, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option you mentioned is the best way. Or at least the most conforming to the REST design.

Comment: If I were to use the second one, how would I get to the user id?
I'm using nodejs with Express.

Comment: I have very little experience with node.js and Express, but you'd need to extract it from the URL in some way. What the best practice is in the tools of your choice, I can't really answer. The Python-based Django mostly uses Regular Expressions to do this.

Comment: @DavidFaiz `app.get('/users/:id', function (req, res) { req.params.id // here it is })`

Comment: I created a sample gist showing some common approaches with express routes handling, chek it here: https://gist.github.com/VzqzAc/a3d76c4e482023f8cae0bf2db1a36bd2

Answer (score 0):

The second option. Similar to: 
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/rest/users/716360178